# Google Sheets trying to match data from two columns on another tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that works as long as all the data it is trying to match from is in Column A. I need this to also look at the data in column B to see if it matches. I also have another formula that matches two different columns and I also need it to look in both A and B for the data. Both of these are used for conditional formatting. Can anyone help me set these up so it is looking on the Received tab in both columns A and B?

**Current formulas that work:**

```
=match($C:$C, indirect("Received!A2:A"),0)

=and(match($I:$I, indirect("Received!A2:A"),0), (match($O:$O, indirect("Received!A2:A"),0)))
```

**What I am trying to do but is not working:**

```
=match($C:$C, indirect("Received!A2:B"),0)

=and(match($I:$I, indirect("Received!A2:B"),0), (match($O:$O, indirect("Received!A2:B"),0)))
```

Test Doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dDrmASkiy4KY8ywVuBLdZzAZtvyTohJBFFWtSte5g8A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=OR(MATCH($C:$C,INDIRECT("Received!A2:A"),0),MATCH($C:$C,INDIRECT("Received!B2:B"),0))
```

and:

```
=OR(AND(MATCH($I:$I,INDIRECT("Received!A2:A"),0),(MATCH($O:$O,INDIRECT("Received!A2:A"),0))),
    AND(MATCH($I:$I,INDIRECT("Received!B2:B"),0),(MATCH($O:$O,INDIRECT("Received!B2:B"),0))))
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not appear to be working. I have added a link to a test sheet for you to see.